# Is there a Prepackaged Vagrant for CodeIgniter?

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, homestead

Is there a pre-packaged Vagrant for CodeIgniter?

What I'm looking for would be an equivalent to Laravel Homestead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this for [vagrant-codeigniter CodeIgniter 2.2.1](https://github.com/paolooo/vagrant-codeigniter). I am not sure if will work in CodeIgniter 3.

And I found a topic on the CodeIgniter forum, *[[Tutorial] Codeigniter on Vagrant](http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-647.html)*.

Comment: It would be better if you summarised the content of the CodeIgniter forum post here.